# the problem with automatic formatting and auto-correction in go

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm experiencing an issue in Visual Studio Code while working with the Go programming language.

When I save a file, automatic code formatting and error correction occur, which is inconvenient for me. I want to save the file without such automatic changes.

I've already tried several methods, such as modifying formatting parameters in the `settings.json` file, including disabling `editor.formatOnSave` and using `go.formatTool`. However, the problem persists. I also used `editor.codeActionsOnSave` to explicitly disable automatic correction, but it didn't help.

Perhaps there are other factors or tools affecting code formatting in my development environment? I would appreciate any additional help in resolving this issue.